# Clarification on using stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm essentially following this guide:

https://rails.devcamp.com/ruby-gem-walkthroughs/payment/how-to-use-a-custom-form-for-stripe

However, I'm confused about two things:

1. What if I want to add additional data to be filled out by the user, such as billing address, zip code, full name, and use that for stripe to verify the credit card with? What do I need to add and where?
2. How do I tell that the payment has gone through? I'm going to be selling an online product -- I need some way to verify that the user has paid successfully in order to unlock access to the product.

Thanks!

Comment: The [stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs) gives you answers to all of your questions.. Stripe is very well documented.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can specify with the [Stripe.js options](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-options-billing-address) whether you would like to add billing and/or shipping address to your checkout form.

2) You can check your payment results by:

- The return value of your API call to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge). Look for the `status` parameter
- Log in to your dashboard and check it there
- Use [Stripe's webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_events), and listen for the `charge.succeeded` event type.